# Recursively merge list of java objects with inner list of same class

Tags: java, recursion, merge, nested

i have a Java Model Class `Item`:

```java
public class Item {

    @JsonProperty(value = "id", required = true)
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty(value = "name", required = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty(value = "result", required = false)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> result;

    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty(value = "items", required = false)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    List<Item> items;
    
    ...
    Getter/Setter
}
```

As a starting point I have a list of items `List<Item>` that I now want to merge recursively, since some of the items have the same ID. But the whole recursively over all hierarchy levels, because each item could have a child list of the same type `List<Item>`.

I have already tried a few things, but I can't make any progress. Does anyone have ideas how to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was there in such situation where we need to parse recursive structure. Additional requirement I had is to preserve the order.

Following sample code (replaced my class with yours)

```
public static List< Item > getItems(Item item) {
        Deque< Item > auxiliaryStack = new LinkedList<>();
        Deque< Item > finalStack = new LinkedList<>();
        auxiliaryStack.push(item);
        while (!auxiliaryStack.isEmpty()) {
            Item currentItem = auxiliaryStack.pop();
            List<Item> subItems = currentItem.getItems();
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(Item)) {
                subItems.forEach(auxiliaryStack::push);
            }
            finalStack.push(currentItem);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(finalStack);
    }
```

Now here I wanted to preserve order and duplicates hence I used list. You can use Set to avoid duplicates.

Hope it helps.

Note: Recursive solutions is not production if your data is not fixed. The solution I implemented is iterative and won't fail even nested items goes on and on. Java has stack size limits, though you can increase it , it may affect performance of the whole system.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! But with this method, I only can add all Childs to the parent item. That's not really purposeful to merge multiple lists with nested child lists of same class.

Comment: You can iterate parent list and call this method on each item  and  you can merge simple plain lists.

Comment: Sorry ignore my previous comment ... you can send list of items to this method and just push them before loop into the stack.  It will iterate all items. In case you want to stop processing duplicates then use set or you can search the final list before putting it .